# getting error try to browse .jtl file with view results tree listener in jmeter 2.13 and 3.2 version

Tags: jmeter

I ran the Jmeter script in non-GUI mode with jmeter 3.2 version using the following command:

```
jmeter -n -t sample.jmx -Rxx.xx.xx.xx,xx.xx.xx.xx,xx.xx.xx.xx | tee -a /x/x/x/x/results.jtl
```

Now when I load the saved `JTL` file into View Results tree listener

[image]

the following error is throwing:

> INFO  - jmeter.save.CSVSaveService: D:\a\b.jtl does not appear to have
>   a valid header. Using default configuration.
>
> WARN  - jmeter.save.CSVSaveService: java.lang.NumberFormatException:
>   For input string: "Creating summariser "
>
> INFO  - jmeter.save.CSVSaveService: Creating summariser  did
>   not match yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
>
> INFO  - jmeter.save.CSVSaveService: Creating summariser  did
>   not match yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss
>
> INFO  - jmeter.save.CSVSaveService: Creating summariser  did
>   not match yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
>
> INFO  - jmeter.save.CSVSaveService: Creating summariser  did
>   not match yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
>
> INFO  - jmeter.save.CSVSaveService: Creating summariser  did
>   not match MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss
>
> WARN  - jmeter.save.CSVSaveService: Error parsing field 'timeStamp' at
>   line 1 java.text.ParseException: No date-time format found matching
>   Creating summariser

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly running JMeter test, you should not be redirecting the output into a file, you need to provide path to results file via `-l` command-line option like:

```
jmeter -n -t sample.jmx -Rxx.xx.xx.xx,xx.xx.xx.xx,xx.xx.xx.xx -l /x/x/x/x/results.jtl
```

After your test finishes you will be able to open `results.jtl` file with the listener of your choice or generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) from it.

References:

- [JMeter: Full List of Command-Line Options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [How Do I Run JMeter in Non-GUI Mode?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)